# How to remove the items from selected items in an array of values using react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs

I have to select the items from an array, but If I have to unselect the item's this error will showing(TypeError: newValue.splice is not a function)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

function Sample(){
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>    
<div>
{DAYS.map((day, i) => (
    <div>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            {...register(`test[${index}].day[${i}]`, {

            })}
            render={({ field, field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                <StyledToggleButtonGroup
                    size="small"
                    {...field}>
                    <StyledToggle key={day.key} value={day.key} aria-label={day.key}>
                        {day.label}
                    </StyledToggle>
                </StyledToggleButtonGroup>
            )}
        />
    </div>
 ))}
</div>
</form>
}
export default Sample;
```